# Pass correct kendo ui dropdown default value to contoller when the page is load

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I use kendo ui dropdownlist to filter my kendo grid

```
$(function () {
    var grid = $("#balanceGrid")
            .kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                             url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Home.GetBalance())",
                            data: additionalParams
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        "data": "Data",
                        "total": "Total"
                    },
                    pageSize: 20,
                    serverPaging: true
                },
                height: 700,
                pageable: true,
                resizable: true,
                dataBound: function(e) {
                },
                columns: [
                    { title: "Period", type: "text", field: "Period" },
                    { title: "Payment sum", type: "text", field: "PaymentSum" },

                ]
            }).getKendoGrid();

    var balanceFilterType = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(EnumExtensions.GetEnumDropdownCollection<EBalanceSortType>()));

    $("#dlPeriodValue").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "Id",
        placeholder: "Period",

        dataSource: balanceFilterType,
        dataBound: function () {
            this.select(0);
            console.log(this.value());
        }
    });



function additionalParams() {
            return {
                PeriodTypes: $("#dlPeriodValue").val(),

            }
        }
```

My contoller has model as parameter. Model has field

```
public int PeriodTypes { get; set; }
```

So controller is next:

```
 public virtual JsonResult GetBalance(GetPaymentBalanceFilterModel model)
        {
            GridModel<GetPaymentBalanceModel> getCustomersResponse = _paymentService.GetBalancePayment(model);

            var response = new
            {
                Data = getCustomersResponse.Data,
                Total = getCustomersResponse.Count
            };
            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I set default value to 1, but when the page first load It pass value "0"(it's incorrect default value) to my controller. Value from my dropdown will be correct pass only when I click button "filter". How can I pass correct dropdown value selected to my contoller when the page first load? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the default value is always going to be '1', then don't do this:

```
dataBound: function () {
        this.select(0);
        console.log(this.value());
    }
```

Instead, explicitly set the value in the constructor:

```
<body>
  <select id="dlPeriodValue"/>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

      var balanceFilterType = [{"Id":1,"Name":"Month"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Quarter"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Year"}];

            $("#dlPeriodValue").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",
            placeholder: "Period",
                    dataSource: balanceFilterType,
                    value: "2"
            });
    alert('after page load: ' + $("#dlPeriodValue").val());
  })

  alert('before page load: ' + $("#dlPeriodValue").val());
  </script>
</body>
```

before page load is `null`, and after page load is "2". Note that value is string, so must be enclosed in quotes.

Here it is in Telerik dojo:

https://dojo.telerik.com/AzateXIP

See:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/configuration/value

Comment: hi , thanks for the asnwer but I tried It , value also 0 , when page first load. Maybe it's wrong because I use JavaScriptSerializer when populate dropdown ?

Comment: Maybe. What does `balanceFilterType` look like when it's printed to the page?

Comment: Do you have an option to use the kendo ASP.Net MVC controls? If so, I find them much easier to work with in my MVC projects than the jQuery controls. Among other things, you can bind them to the page model.

Comment: no, unfortunately I can't use Kendo Asp.Net MVC. `balanceFilterType`  looks next `var balanceFilterType = [{"Id":1,"Name":"Month"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Quarter"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Year"}];` in the page

Comment: That's strange, it seems to work for me. I've updated my post with more specific code.

Comment: something strange I have,too. I have `<input>` html element , I change to  `<select>` and my grid is undefined :/ When there is input all good